# Modifyin module.exports content through another's module function

Tags: node.js

My question might not be so clear at first but I'll explain myself here. I have a file called `firstName.js` which exports to arrays of strings (first names):

```
module.exports = {
  male,
  female
};
```

Those two array ain't alphabetically sorted in that file:

```
const male = [
  'Juan',
  'Carlos',
  'Luis',
  'Miguel',
  'Ángel',
];
```

So, I want to create an utility function that sorts the array alphabetically. My problem is that I don't want so sort the array after importing it in another file, I want so sort it just a single time and modify the content of `firstName.js` in order to have this array sorted as I want.

Now, I know how to create this sorting method, what I want to know is if can create a method inside another file, call it from my terminal with node and modify the file when the sorting method is done.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you want to modify the *source code*  of `firstName.js`, not just the object in memory at runtime, is that it? That's really weird

Comment: I know, it's weird... (? but I want to do so

Comment: Retrieve/manipulate a JSON on the filesystem instead

Comment: You can get clone of the file firstName.js in the starting js file of the application, index.js or app.js. whenever you npm start, it will sort the content of the file, so that other files can use it

Comment: I took both advices and achieve what I wanted; thanks a lot guys!